# Make TextView stretch to its content inside a RecyclerView, to scroll horizontally

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, textview

I have Content inside a RecyclerView that is wider than the screen so I would like to be able to scroll horizontally to see the entire line (for example a long url), but setting "wrap_content" to the width of the TextView, parent linearLayout, RecyclerView itself, and the RecyclerView's parent itself is not working.

I'm sure it's something easy to do but I can't find the solution on SO

Comment: you can use HorizontalScrollview and place text inside it.

Comment: Ah, that is unbelievably simple! I never used that, thanks! If you care to write an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use HorizontalScrollview and place text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stretch (and wrap) the text inside a `TextView`, there is a new solution, autosizing `TextView` is possible in Android 8.0, yet works in older devices (Android 4.0+) with support library. Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) to the documentation. It's quite easy to implement.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work, but thanks for the answer! I used Sandeep's comment instead but you should leave your answer here in case other people would like to try yours :)